# Получение сгенерированной ссылки с заполненной формой html

Tags: python, html, requests, flask

имею простейшую форму с отправкой данных на сервер

***result.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>main</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<form style="font-size: 30px" action="https://httpbin.org/get">

    <h1 style="font-size: 30px">Я думаю, что моя память сейчас лучше, чем была раньше</h1>
    <input  type="radio"  name="control" value="1"> Да
    <input type="radio" name="control" value="2"> Трудно сказать
    <input type="radio" name="control" value="3"> Нет
    <br/>
    <button type="submit"> Завершить тест</button>
    <br/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

При выборе ответов и нажатие кнопки "Завершить тест" генерируется ссылка:

[image: скриншот]

Вот она:
[image: скриншот]

В самом Python я могу обработать полученную ссылку и вытащить данные:

```py
import requests

list1 = []


def GetTest():
    response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get?control=1')
    GetJsonQA = response.json()
    ShowAnswers = GetJsonQA['args']

    for key, value in ShowAnswers.items():
        list1.append(value)
    return print(list1)


GetTest()
```

Соответственно вопрос, как ссылаться на сгенерированную ссылку?

```py
response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get?control=1')
```

Как ее получить, что бы в дальнейшем работать с ней?